# Prevent resizing of child node when resizing parent SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm trying to instantiate a character(skspritenode) and it's health bar(skspritenode). I've made the health bar a child of the character so that it can move wherever the character moves. My problem is that when I scale down the character's `size(setScale(scale: CGFloat))`, the health bar becomes too small. Is there anyway to scale the character down without it affecting the size of the child health bar? Or is there a different way to attach a health bar to a character?

Comment: introduce a parent node, and have your health bar be a sibling to your sprite, then only scale sprite

Comment: you may need to change the position of the health bar to account for change in distance

Comment: didn't even know there could be siblings lol ty I'll look into this